# Boid Particles Loads of errors

Tags: particles, error

I'm setting up a few emitters using the Boid particle system.
But almost every time I run into serious bugs. 
Either the used objects start shaking or won't move at all or do not follow any of the rules set in the boid brain. Objects make sudden direction changes along an axis that should have been nullified
Two emitters on the same layer using different object are leaking variables to each other. (Which in some cases resulted in having emitters launching the same objects when they are set to different ones)

Quite often the only solution is to completely remove the emitter and start all over again. Losing a good hour of tweaking.

Am I doing something completely wrong?  Or do more people suffer from these hideous bugs?

Obviously there are loads of settings which interfere with each other, but it's driving me nuts...

Any good ideas / suggestions would be welcome

Comment: Can you share a blend file exhibiting the problems - or atleast some screenshots? This will help someone replicate the problem.

Comment: Please share a concrete example of this errors. Use the [edit] link to add more information to your question, if you make a simplified file that shows the issue and share it maybe someone here can help you.

Comment: Hi,
thanks for reading it so far.


Mmmm, I better make a screencast then.. screenshot wouldn't reveal that much.
lemme see if I can get to that today or tomorrow.

Additionally, particles tend to disappear or appear.

And... the more emitters, the more issues